# Imaplib in python doesn't connect to gmail host

Tags: python, sockets, imap

I tried using imaplib in python to connect to the the host 'imap.gmail.com'.

```
import imaplib
M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
```

But it doesn't respond. I tried using pdb to see the issue. It goes to the init function of IMAP4_SSL and hangs on open(host, port).
This is the traceback on keyboard interrupt:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 1148, in __init__
IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 163, in __init__
self.open(host, port)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 1159, in open
self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 562, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
```

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: There is no error. It just doesn't respond. On keyboard interrupt it gives the above traceback. It seems like it's not able to make socket connection.

Comment: Are you in China?...

Comment: No. Problem resolved. My company's network was blocking it. Used my personal net connection and it was resolved :)